# MDX SSRS Parameter category chooses all sub category

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have been looking all over stackoverflow for this and I can't figure it out.  So I have a dataset using a SSAS cube, and it has two parameters.  It has a category and subcategory.

I already created the datasets to populate these parameters and they work fine when I select them both.

The way my report runs is that it is a collection of subreports in a table and it is grouped by the category and sub grouped by the subcategory.  So When I select the category parameter, it lists each sub category for all the sub reports.

What I am trying to do is getting a total of all the subcategories within that category.  I tried using default values to ALL but doesnt work.  I tried doing a total on the group within the table but that doesn't work.
So for Group G1 and subgroup SG1 and SG2), and sub reports SR1, SR2, it goes like this

G1

-TOTAL (SG1+SG2+SG3)
---SR1 
---SR2

-SG1
---SR1 
---SR2

-SG2
---SR1 
---SR2

I was able to pull off the Sub group reports parts by setting the category parameter in the sub reports as the parameter passed in for the category, and the sub category parameter as the value of the sub group.  But I need that darn total.

The MDX for My Category is

```
SELECT { } ON COLUMNS, { ([Service].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Sales-Cube] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

The MDX for sub category is

```
 SELECT { } ON COLUMNS, { ([Service].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS * [Service].[SubCategory].[Subcategory].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Sales-Cube] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

The MDX for the dataset I am using the parameters are was created using designer and it is as follows

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( Filter( [Service].[SubCategory].[SubCategory].ALLMEMBERS, Instr( [Service].[SubCategory].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), @ParamSubCategory )  > 0  ) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( Filter( [Service].[Category].[Category].ALLMEMBERS, Instr( [Service].[Category].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), @ParamCategory )  > 0  ) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Sales-Cube])) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

So based on what is selected from the category, it will filter the subcategory to only those within the category so it cascades.
Any resources or help would be great.

Comment: You have to populate Category parameter first, then use its value to populate the Subcategory parameter. Add a sample of the MDX script you are using to populate Subcategory parameter.

Comment: Yes I have two datasets, the one is the category parameter list, then the second data set has the subcategory with the associated category, and it is filtered using the category parameter so when selected it cascades.  This works fine, its just I can not get a total of the whole category, nor can I get the subcategory parameter in the dataset to default to all subcategories within the category if a subcategory is not used.

Comment: Without see the MDX script where you are using your parameters it is hard to determine why it is not getting the category total. Also if you want to show all categories when user Subcategory parameter is null, you can create another parameter as internal/hidden, that checks if subcategory is null, in that case set it to all Subcategories.

Comment: I added the MDX script for my category and sub category. Thank you for looking at this Alejandro

Comment: Where are you using these parameters? Note your parameter is being populated with the dimension members value i.e `Bikes` but it have to be populated with valid qualified member i.e `[Service].[Category].&[Bikes]`.

Comment: The parameters are being used in the shared data set.  In the slicer area in Query designer. does that help

Comment: What is the script for shared dataset?

Comment: I added it to the question post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments you cannot use the Name of your member to slice your cube in MDX, you have to use the [unique name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ms146038.aspx) instead. You have to handle it so when your user selects `Category X` and `Category Y` for your `ParamCategory` parameter, it should be set to `[Service].[Category].&[Category X]` and `[Service].[Category].&[Category Y]`. This is what I'd do.

I'd use an MDX script that returns label (Name) and unique name for populate Category.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Category Label] AS
  [Service].[Category].CurrentMember.Name
MEMBER [Measures].[Category UniqueName] AS
  [Service].[Category].CurrentMember.UniqueName
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Category Label], [Measures].[Category UniqueName] } ON COLUMNS,
{} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales-Cube]
```

In parameter properties / available values you have to use `Category Label` field for `Label field` and `Category UniqueName` for `Value field`.

The same apprach to populate `ParamSubcategory`.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SubCategory Label] AS
  [Service].[SubCategory].CurrentMember.Name
MEMBER [Measures].[SubCategory UniqueName] AS
  [Service].[SubCategory].CurrentMember.UniqueName
SELECT
{ [Measures].[SubCategory Label], [Measures].[SubCategory UniqueName] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Service].[SubCategory].[SubCategory] } ON ROWS
FROM [Sales-Cube]
WHERE ( StrToSet ( @ParamCategory ) )
```

Note I am using `ParamCategory` to populate the `ParamSubcategory` only with the related subcategories.

Now you can use those parameters in your MDX script:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Count] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{
  ( [Date].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].AllMembers )
} Dimension Properties MEMBER_CAPTION,
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT ( STRTOSET( @ParamSubcategory ) ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM (
    SELECT ( STRTOSET ( @ParamCategory ) ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Sales-Cube]
  )
) CELL Properties Value,
BACK_COLOR,
FORE_COLOR,
FORMATTED_VALUE,
FORMAT_STRING,
FONT_NAME,
FONT_SIZE,
FONT_FLAGS
```

Note `Filter` and `InStr` function are not requerid since you are passing the unique name members.

It is not tested but should work, good luck!

Let me know if this helps.