# The STRTOSET function expects a string or numeric expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used

Tags: mdx

I am very new to this whole MDX query thing. I have the following query which I am trying to execute but keep getting the following error:

> Executing the query ...
>   Query (19, 16) The STRTOSET function expects a string or numeric expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used.
>   Execution complete

My query looks as follows:

```
   SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Effective Duration] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { (
                [Dim Cause Code].[Cause].[Cause].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Dim Classification].[Classification].[Classification].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Dim Date 1].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Dim Location 1].[Work Center Name].[Work Center Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Fact Process Downtime].[Start Datetime].[Start Datetime].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Fact Process Downtime].[End Datetime].[End Datetime].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Fact Process Downtime].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) 
            } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( 
    SELECT ( STRTOSET({[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM ( 
            SELECT ( STRTOSET({[Dim Location 1].[Work Center].&[South32 Manganese.Mamatwan.DMS]}, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
            FROM ( 
                    SELECT ( STRTOSET({[Dim Classification].[Classification].&[Scheduled Process]}, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
                    FROM ( 
                            SELECT ( STRTOSET({[Dim Date 1].[Month Fiscal Year].&[Jul/17]}, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [FactDownTime])))) WHERE ( 
    IIF( STRTOSET({[Dim Date 1].[Month Fiscal Year].&[Jul/17]}, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET({[Dim Date 1].[Month Fiscal Year].&[Jul/17]}, CONSTRAINED), [Dim Date 1].[Month Fiscal Year].currentmember ), 
    IIF( STRTOSET(STRTOSET({[Dim Location 1].[Work Center].&[South32 Manganese.Mamatwan.DMS]}, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(STRTOSET({[Dim Location 1].[Work Center].&[South32 Manganese.Mamatwan.DMS]}, CONSTRAINED), [Dim Location 1].[Work Center].currentmember ), 
    IIF( STRTOSET({[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET({[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}, CONSTRAINED), [Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].currentmember ) 
  )))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply strings to this function strToSet is short for "String to Set"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx

So this is incorrect:

```
STRTOSET({[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}, CONSTRAINED)
```

But this is correct

```
STRTOSET('{[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}', CONSTRAINED))
```

The main use case for the strToSet function is when passing parameters into an mdx query from say `SSRS` so syntax like this is seldom used:

```
STRTOSET('{[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}', CONSTRAINED))
```

If parameters are not involved then just get rid of the STRTOSET:

```
{[Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False]}
```

---

If you need to use parameters then check out this excellent recent answer from @ alejandrozuleta:

[MDX SSRS Parameter category chooses all sub category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371875/mdx-ssrs-parameter-category-chooses-all-sub-category)

If parameters are not important then your script can maybe get simplified to something like this:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY [Measures].[Effective Duration] ON 0, 
NON EMPTY 
    [Dim Cause Code].[Cause].[Cause].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Dim Classification].[Classification].[Classification].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Dim Date 1].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Dim Location 1].[Work Center Name].[Work Center Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Fact Process Downtime].[Start Datetime].[Start Datetime].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Fact Process Downtime].[End Datetime].[End Datetime].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Fact Process Downtime].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS 
  ON 1 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        [Fact Process Downtime].[Is Virtual].&[False] ON 0, 
        [Dim Location 1].[Work Center].&[South32 Manganese.Mamatwan.DMS] ON 1, 
        [Dim Classification].[Classification].&[Scheduled Process] ON 2, 
        [Dim Date 1].[Month Fiscal Year].&[Jul/17] ON 3 
    FROM [FactDownTime]
);
```

Comment: Great explanation, it seems to me it is a common question and people doesn't look for too much before ask here. Thanks for referencing my answer but who is @mxix? He deleted his answer?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta apologies - mxix is also a contributor to the mdx tag

Comment: @alejandro: It's not as common as one would think, the heading might be the same but the explanation is not always what one is looking for.