# In SSRS 2016, how do I specify a MDX unique name as a report parameter default?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2016

In SSRS 2016, I'm writing some reports against a Tabular instance.  We're using MDX as the query language.  I'm having issues specifying a default unique name by hand in the report.  **Any ideas?  Is it a bug? An escaping issue?**

We've got a number of parameters where we pull the dimension attributes like this as the available values:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS [Dimension].[Dimension Attribute].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
     MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] AS [Dimension].[Dimension Attribute].CURRENTMEMBER.UniqueName
SELECT {[Measures].[Label], [Measures].[UniqueName] ON 0,
    [Dimension].[Dimension Attribute].Members ON 1
FROM [CubeName]
```

If I try to set the default value by hand, Visual Studio seems to recognize the value, but the SSRS server does not.  I am setting it to:

```
[Line of Business].[Line of Business].[All]
```

SSRS seems to escape this to

```
\[Line of Business\].\[Line of Business\].\[All\]
```

This is also an issue in trying to pass selections among reports as well.  Of note, if I make the default driven by a query, SSRS on the server is happy to select the default:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] AS AS [Dimension].[Dimension Attribute].CURRENTMEMBER.UniqueName
SELECT [Measures].[UniqueName]
FROM [CubeName]
WHERE [Dimension].[Dimension Attribute].[All]
```

Comment: If you specify the parameter default value as a string in SSRS, you have to use STRTOSET function in your MDX script. Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS the default value should be a string with the unique name of your dimension member, in this case:

```
="[Line of Business].[Line of Business].[All]"
```

Now in your dataset you have to use MDX STRTOSET function, with the purpose of string value in your parameter be intepreted as a valid set of `[Line Of Business]` dimension members.

```
SELECT 
  StrToSet
  (@BusinessLineParam
   ,CONSTRAINED
  ) ON ROWS
 ,[Measures].[Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Sales Cube];
```

Check a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371875/mdx-ssrs-parameter-category-chooses-all-sub-category/39394332#39394332) I posted recently. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407574/the-strtoset-function-expects-a-string-or-numeric-expression-for-the-1-argument/39409450#39409450) could help you.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Strangely enough, this worked, but with a caveat - any parameters without a default must have a value selected before these defaults activate.  I had actually tried that before, but since I had a parameter without a default set, it looked like the parameter defaults were not taking.

Comment: @SteveCardella, Yep, If your parameter is not set to allow null values it must have a selected value when default value is missing. Glad you managed to solve it.